# How do I change background color of one Excel 2013 based on the value in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wanting to change the background color of a cell when it reaches the value of another cell. i.e. when the value in R10 = the value in H10+10 I would like the background to change color.I also want the cells in those columns to be independent of each other i.e. when cell R5 = H5+10 I would like R5 to change color but not any of the other cells in column R

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting:

1. Select your data (the cells that want formatting (e.g. cell turns red)).
2. Press Alt, then O, then press D -- is the shortcut to Condition Formatting.
3. Set Condition 1 to: "Cell Value Is", "euqual to", =$D$1+10.

Where D1 is the comparing cell value that you label H10 in your question. 
The column selected A1:A8 (all cells selected) refers to your R10.

This is like saying "For each cell in this selection, check to see if any value is equal to the value in D1+10, if so paint this cell red.

Here is the illustration worth a thousand words.

[image: 1]

You stated that you want to compare cell by cell to another cell. In that case just select one cell to be formatted conditionally, but know that you can apply it to many cells at the same time.